# Fast user switching is logging users off instead of switching users

Tags: windows-8, fast-user-switching

I have a netbook running Windows 8.1 Pro that will no longer allow more than one user to be logged in at the same time. The steps necessary to reproduce this are as follows:

1. The current user presses <kbd>WIN</kbd> to bring up the start screen.
2. The user clicks his name in the corner and a list of other users appears.
3. As soon as one of the other names is clicked, the user is unceremoniously logged off without any prompts.

This behavior seems to have started some time after upgrading to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8. Before that point, everything worked fine and more than one user could be logged in at the same time. I've tried searching for others experiencing similar problems but this appears to be unique.

System Details:

- CPU: Intel Atom N455 @ 1.66 GHz
- RAM: 1 GB
- OS: Windows 8.1 Pro w/ Media Center 32-bit

---

**Update:** I tried the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> trick, which produces this dialog:

[image]

However, the dialog box is lying. When the user switches back, all applications are closed.

Comment: They indeed changed the fast user switch. And the part of being unable to have two accounts logged on at the same time is true too. kinda sucks.

Comment: Related: [Is there a hard limit to the number of users that can be logged on to a single Windows 7 workstation using Fast User Switching?](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-7/q-there-hard-limit-number-users-can-be-logged-single-windows-7-workstation-using-fast-user). Even Windows 7 had a limit on *active* sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking both:

1. Use regedit to go to the key:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`.
   Create a DWORD entry named `HideFastUserSwitching` and set its value to 0.
2. Type Group Policy in the Start Screen and then click on the Settings category. 
   Click on the Edit Group Policy option and under the Local Computer Policy expand the tree to the following path:
   `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon`.
   Double-click on Hide entry points for Fast User Switching,
   select Not Configured and then click on OK.
   Then open the Run dialog box and enter the command `gpupdate /force` and click OK.

For both methods, try rebooting if they don't work at first.
It would be interesting to know if the above settings existed already on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have windows 8.1 myself, but according to this

http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-8&faq=59

and

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-enabledisable-fast-user-switching-in-windows-8/

I get the impression that fast user switching has changed in windows 8.1

so could you try out the instructions in the first link and tell me if it's any better?

P.S. I googled windows 8.1 fast user switching
and windows 8.1 switch users